# Como marcar checkbox con variable registrada con php

Tags: php, checkbox

tengo el siguiente checkbox

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="si">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Este checkbox se selecciona y se guarda en la base de datos con el valor de ejemplo: SI

lo que estoy buscando hacer es que al ver nuevamente el checkbox en pantalla ya que tiene una variable registrada debería marcarlo como seleccionado pero no se como hacer eso. ya intente colocándole un value e imprimiendo la variable de la base de datos pero no funciona.

Que podría hacer en ese caso?

En si la idea es que si el checkbox ya tiene el Si registrado que lo marque como seleccionado.

Comment: usa el atributo checked dentro de la etiqueta cuando deba estar marcado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que agregarle el atributo `checked` al `<input>` de esta manera:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Si" <?php if ($is_checked) echo "checked"; ?> />
```

Comment: Perfecto, asi me funciono como queria, muchas gracias @El Pane.

Comment: Por favor consulta esta sección de la especificación para el futuro [Html Boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), Es importante saber qué se está haciendo, obtener el resultado no basta.